# Unable to write Javascript function into Typescript using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My objective is to Validate form. When we submit form with empty fields then it should show errors.
I have wrriten Validation function in Javascript but couldn't able to convert it into typescript.

JSX function code:

```
  validation = (error) => {
        let valid = true;
        Object.keys(error).map((key: string) => {
            this.onChange(key, this.state[key]);
            if (this.state.error[key].length)
                valid = false;
        });
        return valid;
    }
```

error contains:

```
error = {name:"", age: "", college: "", experience: ""}
```

If i write the same function in Typescript in a same way, it is throwing error: ***Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Readonly'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Readonly'***

Can anyone help me in this query?

Comment: With arrow functions `this` is taken from the outer scope, so you don't need to do `that`.

Comment: @elclanrs - Still i'm getting error

Comment: I'll post a solution in a moment

Comment: @AlexMckay - Okay

Comment: @Sandhya I have provided two solutions below

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put explicit the type in error variable

```
validation = (error: {name: string, age: string, college: string, experience: string}): boolean => {
        let valid = true;
        let that = this;
        Object.keys(error).map((key: string) => {
            that.onChange(key, that.state[key]);
            if (that.state.error[key].length)
                valid = false;
        });
        return valid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fix the issue by doing this but your code is a bit strange so I've written an example that might help your write a simpler form [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-ride-3ydup?file=/src/App.tsx). However, if you want your existing code to work:

```js
type ErrorTypes = 'name' | 'age' | 'experience' | 'college'

  validation = (error: Record<ErrorTypes, string>) => {
        let valid = true;
        Object.keys(error).map((key: string) => {
            this.onChange(key, this.state[key]);
            if (this.state.error[key].length)
                valid = false;
        });
        return valid;
    }
```